# amazon cloud ec2 xampp username and password

Tags: amazon-ec2, xampp, instance

I am connecting to an ec2 (amazon cloud) windows instance with xampp, but it requires username and password. Where can I find them?

Comment: Which AMI are you actually using here (your comment suggests this might in fact be required information for answering the question in the first place)?

Answer (score 0):

This is documented in the [Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud Microsoft Windows Guide](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/Welcome.html), specifically in [Step 3: Connect to Your Windows Instance](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/EC2Win_GetStarted.html#EC2Win_ConnectToInstanceWindows) within the *Getting Started* section:

> To connect to a Windows instance, you must first retrieve the initial
>   administrator password, and then use this password with Remote
>   Desktop. You'll need the contents of the private key file that you
>   created when you launched the instance (e.g., GSG_Keypair.pem).

The detailed actions required to achieve this are documented and illustrated on the aforementioned page.

Good luck!

Comment: I do can connect to the remote desktop, the problem is that in order to connect to localhost/xampp it requires username and password

Comment: @george: I'm afraid I can't follow, the procedure described should be all you need to login to the Windows desktop as an administrator and work from there just as you would with your local machine. In other words, from _where_ do you want to connect to _which specific service_ by means of _which tool_ after having logged into the Windows desktop already? In case you are asking for the MySQL password for example, that would obviously be specific to the AMI you are using, which you haven't specified.